# Removing array elements when string matches tags

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to remove elements from an array if a value in that array matches a given string.

I have an array that is has a tags array. I am comparing the names of the tags to see if they match what the user wishes to exclude from their search. If it does I would like to either remove that element from the main array, or else possibly add the element that does not match.

Here is what I have so far:

```rb
results = Array.new
test = 0
no_tags.each do |no_tag| #an array of tags whose resources are not to be included
  resources.each do |r|
    add_to_array = false
    r.tags.each do |t|
      if t.name.eql? no_tag
        test += 1
        add_to_array = false
      else
        add_to_array = true
      end
    end

    if add_to_array
      results << r
    end
  end
end
```

The *test* variable is just a variable for debugging the number of matching occurrences which happens to be 141 out of 763 resources. However when I do results.count after this block is run I only get 732 when I should be getting 622.

To clarify I need to either delete the element of the resource array if the tags array contains a match, or the other option would be to include the resource array element into a new array if a match is not found.

This will be returned to the browser as JSON and I need to exclude resources whose tags match the values of the no_tags array.

Comment: If a resource has more than one tag, the decision to include it is based **only** on the very last of it's tags. That's probably where the difference comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@steenslag gave me the idea that offered up the solution for my problem.

```rb
resources.delete_if do |resource| 
  (resource.tags.map(&:name) & no_tags).present? 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test the intersection of the names and the no_tags. It should be empty.

```
results = resources.select do |r|
  (r.tags.map(&:name) & no_tags).empty?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `test` for each *tag* in a resource that is an element of your blacklist, but your results count is counting the number of *resources* you are keeping.  Assuming there is more than one tag per resource, you are over-counting.

If your intent is to exclude every resource object where at least one tag matches your blacklist, you should not be setting add_to_array to true inside of your inner loop.  Here's a more ruby-like attempt (note: untested)

```
results = Array.new
test = 0
resources.each do |r|
  # are any tags elements of no_tags?
  if (r.tags & no_tags).blank? # "&": set intersection
    results << r
  else
    test += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `delete_if`?

```
resources.delete_if! { |r| (r.tags & no_tags).present? }
```